# ¿Como transferir una TableView desde otra TableView usando los segue?

Tags: xcode, swift3

Se como transferir información de una TableViewController a una ViewController, pero necesito ahora pasar a otra TableViewController usando la función `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`, ademas creo que se necesita modificar el valor que devuelve `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` dependiendo de cuantas celdas tenga cada tabla ¿no es así?

Es decir, que cada celda te dirija una TableViewController distinta y esa otra TableViewController tenga distinto numero de celdas que el resto.

Dejo mi código de como paso información de una TableViewController a un ViewController para que me puedan ayudar con los cambios que debo realizar, gracias comunidad. :)

```
var recipes : [Recipe] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var recipe = Recipe(name: "Tortilla de patatas",
                        ingredients: ["Patatas", "Huevos", "Cebolla"])
    recipes.append(recipe)

    recipe = Recipe(name: "Pizza margarita",
                    ingredients: ["Harina", "Levadura", "Aceite", "Sal", "Salsa de Tomate", "Queso"])
    recipes.append(recipe)

}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.recipes.count
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showRecipeDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let selectedRecipe = self.recipes[indexPath.row]
            let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
            destinationViewController.recipe = selectedRecipe
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo haber entendido que lo que quieres no es pasar una de las recetas a un UIViewController sino a un UITableViewController, imagino que para mostrar los ingredientes como una nueva tabla
(Aunque no sea exactamente eso debería servirte)

Debes crear otro UITableViewController como el que muestras con algunos cambios:

```
var recipe : Recipe?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = recipe.name //puedes usar esto para poner el nombre de la receta como título de la nueva lista
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.recipe.ingredients.count
}
```

De esta forma en el código que ya tienes solo tendrías que cambiar el DetailViewController por este nuevo UITableViewController